# Complexity Analysis of Nested Loops with Sigma Notation

Tags: summation, algorithms, notation, asymptotics

There are two nested for loops. I'm not sure but I think that it's geometric series, but I cannot get well solution for it. What I tried is below up to now,

$$ \sum _{i=0}^{log\left(n-1\right)}\:\sum _{j=0}^{i-1}\:1 $$
$$ \sum _{i=0}^n\:\sum _{j=0}^n\:\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j $$

At first, I thought it's $O(nlogn)$ but instead as far as I research the right result is  $O(n)$.

```
int try(int n) {   
    int sum = 0;   
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2) {     
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {      
          sum += 1; 
          }
    }  
    return sum;
}
```

Could you show its sigma notation with its complexity? I want to comprehend it.

Comment: Are you sure your return statement is aligned correctly? Also, is your question about algorithm complexity? or how big is the output?

Comment: it's aligned now better and about algorithm complexity. @SiongThyeGoh

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is basically how many times the "sum+=1;" line is executed, since it is the line that is executed most often. How many times then?

$$n+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{2^2}\rfloor+\cdots\leq n+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2^2}+\cdots=2n.$$

So the time complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n)$, as the run time of the code is bounded by a constant times $n$.

Comment: I have found the solution but I can't grasp it. $ \frac{n}{\:2}+\:\frac{n}{4}\:+\:\frac{n}{8}+\:...\:+\:\frac{n}{n^2} $. How did you obtain it? Also, could you show its sigma notations?

Comment: The sigma notation is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor$ for the left-hand side. The floor is less than equal to the number itself. Then we sum a geometric series. There are only a finite number of nonzero terms in the sum of floors. Every term corresponds to one value of $i$.